# How to store Javascript Code in MongoDB using Doctrine

Tags: javascript, mongodb, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I am trying to store javascript code in MongoDB field. But i dont know what annotation we have to use for that. I found that it has to be stored in following format. Can anyone please tell me in which annotation the below format should be stored?

```
new \MongoCode($javascriptCode);  -> In which annotation this value to be stored.
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally i found the answer for my question. We have to use `@Hash` annotation for this.